# Read from MemoryStream using StreamReader without closing it VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, tcp, stream, garbage-collection

I'm trying to create a class for handling multiple Tcp connections. The problem is that I write the data sent from client in a MemoryStream. The I have to read the first line from the stream and see if it contains "[ID]". It seems that once I try to read it using:

```
Using sr as new StreamReader(data_stream)
   If sr.readLine="[id]" then
      ' Code
   End If

End Using
```

it closes the stream.I tried even creating a dublicate (I don't want too many dublicates because I will send large-size data over tcp so it will fill the RAM). I have then to send the memorystream in a event. Even if the stream was sent ByVal it still closed it when I used a StreamReader. I don't want to leave the GC to take care of the un-closed Stream Readers( I tried another class made by me-also for Tcp- and the GC was being called MANY times in a row..and the application used 27 MB of RAM because of dublicates-I was sending multiple pictures). Is it ok to use a buffer (an array of bytes) and leave the memory stream? Or should I let the GC to do the job for me?

Here's a part from the class:

```
Sub receive_header(ar As IAsyncResult)
    received_size += client_stream.EndRead(ar)

    If received_size = 0 Then
        RaiseEvent Internal_Disconnected(New Exception("Connection closed normally"))
    Else
        If received_size < client_header_size Then
            client_stream.BeginRead(buffer, received_size, client_header_size - received_size, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf receive_header), client_stream)
        Else
            received_size = 0
            client_header = readHeader(buffer)

            Array.Clear(buffer, 0, client_header_size)

            client_stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf receive_data), client_stream)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
Sub receive_data(ar As IAsyncResult)
    received_size += client_stream.EndRead(ar)

    If received_size = 0 Then
        RaiseEvent Internal_Disconnected(New Exception("Connection closed normally"))
    Else
        data_stream.Write(buffer, 0, received_size)

        If received_size < client_header.PACK_SIZE Then
            'TODO: Here can be made an optimization
            ' Buffer has a length of client_stream.EndRead(ar). So take that instead of adding to received_size
            Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

            client_stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf receive_data), client_stream)
        Else
            received_size = 0


            ' Send data to user if canSend
            If canSend Then
                data_stream.Position = 0

                ' If in this event I use stream reader it closes the main stream althought it is passed byVal
                RaiseEvent New_Message(Me, data_stream)
            End If

            ' Check first line
            data_stream.Position = 0

            Dim sr As New StreamReader(data_stream)
            If sr.ReadLine = "[ID]" Then
                canSend = True

                With client
                    .ID = sr.ReadLine.Split("=")(1)
                    .Computer_Name = sr.ReadLine.Split("=")(1)
                    .Win_Ver = sr.ReadLine.Split("=")(1)
                End With
            End If


            ' Reset
            data_stream.Close()
            data_stream = New MemoryStream

            Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            client_stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, client_header_size, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf receive_header), client_stream)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can see in **receive_data** function I only 2048 bytes from the buffer. If the message is longer I reuse the buffer but not before I save the data in **data_stream**. How can I pass **data_stream** throught the event and read it without closing it?

Comment: That's a lot of stuff to read... but there is a `StreamReader` [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712952(v=vs.110).aspx) that lets you leave the stream open (see the `leaveOpen` parameter), if that is what you are looking for?

Comment: If I keep it open the it will occupy meny space in RAM. Isn't there any way around?

Comment: It is (from the first example) the `data_stream` that is kept open when you dispose of the `StreamReader`, which I thought is what you want (but I could be wrong :-).

Comment: You can leave the `MemoryStream` open and set its `Capacity` property to a minimal value.  Setting the `Capacity` recreates the internal buffer.  You should review the [documentation for the MemoryStream Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx).